# Sorting an array that is 2 way bound causes HTML elements to be reordered, which gives wrong control focus

Tags: vuejs2

**UPDATE 2**: Found a solution that works (using unique properties of an object to index).  Didn't want to rely on an object having unique properties, but this'll do.

Thanks to all who voluntarily bonked their head against the wall to help me find a solution!

**UPDATE**:  *I've been told that using keys will help keep track of sorted UI elements, though when I attempt to use them for this purpose, they do not work. 
 Why?  (Code examples provided below)*

**Brief description of my project:**

Project has a table with rows and columns bound to a javascript object array that is returned by a *computed property*.

The computed property sorts and returns javascript object array items that are two-way bound to HTML elements (dropdown lists), when the selected value of a single dropdown list is changed by the user.

The computed property does what it's supposed to do when it returns sorted array items, but the focus on the original item is lost and given to a new html element that lives in the same location as the original.

What is the best practice in Vue2 for maintaining focus after two-way bound items are resorted?

**Here are screenshots:**

[image: Original Values]

[image: During selection]

[image]

**HTML:**

```
             <table class="tg" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">
              <tr>
                <td v-for="header, index in getFinanceColumns" :key="`financeColumn-${index}`">
                  <span v-if="index > 0">
                    <!--:options="finance.cashOptions"-->
                    <b-form-select v-model="header.header"
                                   :options="getCashOptions('finance', index)"
                                   @change.native="columnChanged('finance', index)"
                                   class="mb-2 selectwidthauto noHighlight">
                    </b-form-select>
                  </span>
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr v-for="row, index in getFinanceRows" :key="`financeRow-${index}`">
                <td>
                  <b-form-select v-model="row.Term"
                                 @change.native="rowChanged($event, 'finance', index)"
                                 :options="getTermOptions('finance', index)"
                                 :ref="'financeRow' + index"
                                 class="mb-2 selectwidthauto noHighlight">
                  </b-form-select>
                </td>

                <td v-for="column, index2 in row.Programs">
                  <div v-if="!isNaN(row.Term)">
                    <span v-if="!isChanged('finance', finance.fields[index2+1], row)"
                          @click="onClickedProgram('finance', finance.fields[index2+1].header, column, row)"
                          style="cursor: pointer">
                      <span>${{ typeof column.Payment === 'undefined' ? '0.00' : column.Payment }}</span>
                    </span>
                    <span v-else style="font-weight: bold">$0.00</span>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
```

**Computed Properties:**

```
  getFinanceRows() {
    this.finance.financeRows.sort(function (a, b) {
      return parseInt(a.Term) - parseInt(b.Term)
    })

    return this.finance.financeRows
  },

  getFinanceColumns() {
    this.finance.fields.sort(function (a, b) {
      if (a.header === ' ' || b.header === ' ')
        return 0

      return a.header - b.header
    })

    return this.finance.fields
  },


     finance: {
      fields: [
        { header: ' ', changed: false }, // should always be a whitespace
        { header: 1000, changed: false },
        { header: 2000, changed: false },
        { header: 3000, changed: false },
        { header: 4000, changed: false },

      ],

      cashOptions: [1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000, 3500, 4000, 4500, 5000],
      termOptions: defaultFinanceTermOptions,

      financeRows: defaultFinanceRows
    },
```

**"Finance row" JSON looks like this:**

```
{
  Term: 72,
  Programs: [{ Payment: '0.00' }, { Payment: '0.00' }, { Payment: '0.00' }, { Payment: '0.00' }],
  changed: false,
},
```

Comment: are you using `:key` with a unique value in your `v-for` node?
can you add some code?

Comment: Yes, but they are not working.  I provided the code above.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need a key that doesn't depend on the position of the row, in this case `index`, since you are reordering them.

You can add a property inside each element of `financeRows`, something like `uniqueId` that doesn't change when you do the sort and use it in the `v-for`:

```
<tr v-for="row in getFinanceRows" :key="`financeRow-${row.uniqueId}`">
```

Comment: Worked.  Didn't want to rely on unique properties, but since this solution worked, I'll leave this task alone and maybe come back to it later.  Thank you very much!